# How does $\frac{-(3-\sqrt{3})}{(3+\sqrt{3})}$ become $\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{1+\sqrt{3}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How can I change $\dfrac{-(3-\sqrt{3})}{(3+\sqrt{3})}$ to $\dfrac{1-\sqrt{3}}{1+\sqrt{3}}$?

Background:

I tried solving $\tan(345°)$ with the trigonometric angle ***sum/difference*** identity.

I used $\tan(45°-30°)$ to find $\tan(15°)$.

I then used $\tan(360°-15°)$ to get $\tan(345°)$.

I used the identity:
$$\tan(\theta \pm \phi)=
\frac{\tanθ \pm tan \phi}{1 \mp \tanθ×\tan\phi}$$

My answer was $\frac{-(3-√3)}{(3+√3)}$ but the answer given was $\frac{(1-√3)}{(1+√3)}$.

I used a calculator to find out these are one and the same.

> [image]

However, without using a calculator, How would I be able to transform my answer to the given answer.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. In order to make it easy for readers to understand your post, you should typeset your mathematical formulas using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $\frac{-(3-√3)}{(3+√3)}=\frac{\sqrt3(1-√3)}{\sqrt3(1+√3)}=\frac{ 1-√3}{(1+√3} $

Comment: $\tan(30^\circ)=1/\sqrt3=\sqrt3/3.$ I'm guessing you decided to simplify things by multiplying numerator and denominator by $3.$ If you had multiplied by $\sqrt3$ instead, you would have gotten the result from the answer key. Another way to solve it is $\tan(60^\circ-45^\circ),$ which gets you the given answer almost directly. Note that you can conclude $\tan(345^\circ)=-\tan(15^\circ)$ without using an angle-sum formula.

Comment: Divide numerator and denominator by $\sqrt3$

Answer (score 1):

To solve these kinds of problems, it's helpful to multiply by the conjugate. In our case, the conjugate of $a + b \sqrt{3}$ is $a - b \sqrt{3}$.

Therefore, we have $\frac{-(3 - \sqrt{3})}{ 3 + \sqrt{3}} = \frac{-(3 - \sqrt{3})( 3 - \sqrt{3})}{( 3 + \sqrt{3}) ( 3 - \sqrt{3}) }$.

The denominator is a difference of squares and simplifies to $6$. The numerator becomes $-12 + 6 \sqrt{3}$. Therefore, the left side is $-2 + \sqrt{3}$.

For the right side, we have $\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{1+\sqrt{3}} = \frac{(1-\sqrt{3})(1-\sqrt{3})}{(1+\sqrt{3})(1-\sqrt{3})}$.

The denominator is again a difference of squares and is equal to $-2$. The numerator is $4 - 2 \sqrt{3}$. Therefore, the right side is $-2 + \sqrt{3}$. They're the same.

Comment: It's curious that the answer key did not use this simplification.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{-(3-\sqrt{3})}{3+\sqrt{3}} = \frac{\sqrt{3} - 3}{3+\sqrt{3}} = \frac{3 \cdot (\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} - 1)}{3 \cdot (1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})} = \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}} = \frac{\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}}{\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}} = \frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{1+\sqrt{3}} = \frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{1+\sqrt{3}}$.